# Bash Script running on Server, accessing local files

Tags: linux, bash

I´m running a script on a server that is supposed to copy all files from the source directory x-times to the destinaton directory. It´s running fine when both directorys are on the server.

How can i copy from a local directory like C:\dir to the server directory?

Comment: You will have to use some protocol, such as sftp, scp or similar.

Comment: are you trying to get the server to retrieve files from the local system with a bash script running on server?

Comment: If one of the systems is Windows, that should probably be reflected in the question's title and tagging

Comment: you can setup a webdav share using the servers webserver then conect as a network drive from windows

Comment: There's a great deal of context which this question doesn't specify. How should the server determine which system to pull files from? What software is the client using to connect to the server? Do you control the client's software stack? If you want something which will allow a server to access files local to any arbitrary SSH client without prior configuration, the answer will simply be "no, that's not possible" (by intent, for very good security-driven reasons).

Answer (score 1):

If you have SSH access between the systems, you can push a local directory to a remote location like so:

```
printf -v ssh_cmd 'mkdir -p %q && tar -C %q -x' \
  "$dest_directory" "$dest_directory"
tar -C "$source_directory" -c . | ssh other_host "$ssh_cmd"
```

...or pull a remote directory to a local one similarly:

```
printf -v ssh_cmd 'tar -C %q -c .' \
  "$source_directory" "$source_directory"
mkdir -p "$dest_directory"
ssh other_host "$ssh_cmd" | tar -C "$dest_directory" -x
```

Comment: If one of the systems is Windows, this will work with cygwin. (It may be necessary to start Cygwin sshd as a service, but this is a thing that's available).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to share your local "C:\dir" and give it a network name, like "networkdir".

Then, you mount it like that
`mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=pw //hostname/networkdir /mnt/localdir/`

Then you copying files to `/mnt/localdir/` like you do it to a local directory.

For secirity reasons, you can also create user in windows just for this operation and give the user permission to write to that share

Comment: The Problem is that this Script is supposed to be useable by anyone in my company. And I guess everyone had to share the local directory then?

Comment: well, my solution requires directory to be shared. have you tried the other one?